# Insert a new line after matching some text in bash

Tags: shell, sorting, awk

I have a file:

```
aaaa_bbb_ccc: something
aaaa_ddd_zzz: something
bbbb_ccc_ddd: something
bbbb_ccc_eee: something
bbbb_ddd_eee: something
bbbb_ddd_fff: something
bbbb_eee_ggg: something
```

I want to insert a new line, basically sort by first word and then group alphabetically by second to have something like:

```
aaaa_bbb_ccc: something

aaaa_ddd_zzz: something

bbbb_ccc_ddd: something
bbbb_ccc_eee: something

bbbb_ddd_eee: something
bbbb_ddd_fff: something

bbbb_eee_ggg: something
```

I've tried `awk 'NR>1 && a && substr($1,1,1)!=a{ print "" }{ a=substr($1,1,1) }1'` but that only inserts after first word.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this awk one-liner a try:

```
awk -F'_' '{k=$1FS$2}k!=p&&NR>1{print ""}7;{p=k}' file
```

This works for the given example. Your input file must be sorted and not exist empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk, assuming sorted input as you have in the question

```
awk -F"_" ' { c=$2;if(c!=p && NR>1) { print "" } print ; p=c; } ' file
```

Comment: That would fail given contiguous lines like `a_x` then `b_x`?

Comment: You have to include $1 when creating the key - `c=$1 FS $2`. Of course then it'd be identical to [@Kent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55491325/1745001)